# Lie derivative of a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative, exterior-derivative

I have a differential $1$-form $\omega = x\mathrm{d}x + x\mathrm{d}y$ and I need to find its Lie derivative along $X = (x+y)\partial_{x} - 2y\partial_{y}$. The first approach is by using Cartan identity:
\begin{multline}
\imath_{X} \omega = x\mathrm{d}x\left((x+y)\partial_{x} - 2y\partial_{y}\right) + x\mathrm{d}y\left((x+y)\partial_{x} - 2y\partial_{y}\right) = \\ = x(x + y) - 2xy = x^2-xy; 
\end{multline}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}(\imath_{X}\omega) = \mathrm{d}\left(x^{2} - xy\right) = 2x\mathrm{d}x - y\mathrm{d}x - x\mathrm{dy} = (2x - y)\mathrm{d}x - x\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
Next
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\omega = \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}x + \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y;
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
\imath_{X}(\mathrm{d}\omega)  = \imath_{X}(\mathrm{d}x\otimes\mathrm{d}y - \mathrm{d}y\otimes\mathrm{d}x) = \\ = \mathrm{d}x((x+y)\partial_{x} -2y\partial_{y})\mathrm{d}y - \mathrm{d}y((x+y)\partial_{x} -2y\partial_{y})\mathrm{d}x = \\ = (x+y)\mathrm{d}y + 2y\mathrm{d}x
\end{multline}
Finally, using the Cartan identity
\begin{multline}
\mathfrak{L}_{X}\omega = \mathrm{d}(\imath_{X}\omega) + \imath_{X}(\mathrm{d} \omega) = (2x - y)\mathrm{d}x - x\mathrm{d}y + (x + y)\mathrm{d}y + 2y\mathrm{d}x = \\ = (2x + y)\mathrm{d}y + y\mathrm{d}y
\end{multline}
However I’d like to find it using flow definition. As I understand the flow could be found in this manner
\begin{gather}
\begin{cases}\dot{x} = x + y\\ \dot{y} = -2y\end{cases}\\
\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}e^{t} & \frac{e^{t}- e^{-2t}}{3}\\ 0 & e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x(0) \\ y(0)\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
Therefore, flow is
\begin{equation}
\Phi^{t}(x_{0},y_{0}) = \begin{pmatrix}e^{t} & \frac{e^{t}- e^{-2t}}{3}\\ 0 & e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

From here I don’t quite understand how to find a pullback lift $h^{t}(x,y)$ and Lie derivative from here, using definition
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{L}_{X}\omega = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{h^{t}_{(x,y)}(\omega(\Phi^{t}(x,y))) - \omega(x,y)}{t}
\end{equation}

And the last thing: is this a correct formula
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{L}_{X}\omega = \left(X^{j}\frac{\omega_{i}}{\partial{x}_{j}} + \omega_{j}\frac{\partial X^{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{i}?
\end{equation}
As I understand it is a coordinate representation of Cartan identity. I saw it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876926/concrete-example-of-the-lie-derivative-of-a-one-form), however there are some troubles in upper and lower indexes in it and it does not give a correct answer for my example.

Comment: RHS of your formula should be $\partial X^j$ over $\partial x_i$, which is consistent with Einstein summation convention

Comment: Yeah, that jarred me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your flow is:

$$\phi^t(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{t} & \frac{e^{t}- e^{-2t}}{3}\\ 0 & e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^tx+Ey\\e^{-2t}y\end{pmatrix}$$

where $E=E(t)=\frac{e^t-e^{-2t}}{3}$ to save space.

Then, fixing $t$, the pull back form

\begin{align}
 (\phi^t)^*\omega &=(e^tx+Ey)d(e^tx+Ey)+(e^tx+Ey)d(e^{-2t}y)\\
&=e^t(e^tx+Ey)dx+(E+e^{-2t})(e^tx+Ey)dy
\end{align}
Now, you need to compute
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\phi^t)^*\omega -\omega}{t}$$
This is a direct computation, using
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{2t}-1}t=2, \;\;\lim_{t\to 0}E=0,\;\;\lim_{t\to 0}\frac Et=1,\;\;\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{-t}-1}{t}=-1$$
and you will get your desired answer.

In terms of coordinates, $\omega=\omega_idx^i$.

Then,

$$\mathcal L_X\omega=\mathcal L_X\omega_idx^i+\omega_i\mathcal L_X dx^i$$
$$\mathcal L_X\omega_i=X^j\partial_j\omega_i$$
$$\mathcal L_X(dx^i)=\partial_jX^i dx^j$$

So your formula is almost correct, just an index mistake at the end.

FYI, you can work from the definition and you don't need Cartan formula to compute $\mathcal L_X dx^i$:
\begin{align}
(\mathcal L_X dx^i)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)&=\partial_X \left(dx^i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\right)-dx^i\left(\left[X,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right]\right)\\
&=-dx^i\left(\left[X,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right]\right)\;\;\;\;\;\text{because }\; dx^i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)=\delta^i_j\\
&=\partial_jX^i
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! It really sheds more light on forms!